# SVG custom tooltip on hover following mouse movement

Tags: svg, hover, tooltip, rect

I'm tinkering [here on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yk810tar/4/). The issue faced is that onmouseleave the 3rd rect has the inscription left if any of the other rect are hovered. Can someone fix this? So that onmouseleave the tooltip disappears completely?

---

Initial msg. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pc7o4mze/1/).

The tooltip needs to follow the cursor. I've used a similar code with image area tags. But it was wrapped around div tags. I read div tags should not be used with SVG and one can substitute them with g tags. At present the result is that a rect is separate and the text is visible.

Side note. I intend to put both, images and text inside a tooltip later.

HTML

```
 <svg>
 
   <g class="tooltip"><rect x="10" y="10" width="100" height="50"><span id="tooltip-span1">Some text</span></rect></g>
  
 </svg>
```

CSS

```
.tooltip {
    text-decoration:none;
    position:relative;
}
.tooltip span {
    display:none;
}
    
.tooltip:hover span {
    display:block;
    color:aliceblue;
    font-size:24pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding:10px;
    border: 1px solid coral;
    position:fixed;
    overflow:hidden;
     text-shadow: -1px 3px 0px #000,
                          1px 3px 3px #000,
                         1px -1px 3px #000,
                        -1px -1px 3px #000;
}
```

Javascript

```
var tooltipSpan1 = document.getElementById('tooltip-span1');
    
window.onmousemove = function (a) {
    var d = a.clientX,
        c = a.clientY;
    tooltipSpan1.style.top = (c + 20) + 'px';
    tooltipSpan1.style.left = (d + 20) + 'px';  
};
```

The tooltip needs to follow the cursor. I've used a similar code with image area tags. But it was wrapped around div tags. I read div tags should not be used with SVG and one can substitute them with g tags. At present the result is. A rect is separate and the text is visible. I intend to put both, images and text inside a tooltip later.

Comment: Can you post a video / screenshot(s) of this please?  I can not recreate your bug.  Thanks!